# How can I include or exclude a record according to a boolean parameter in this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I have the following SQL doubt (I am working on MySql)

I have this **Accomodation** table:

```
id                bigint(20) unsigned   NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
id_accomodation   bigint(20) unsigned   NO  MUL     NULL    
is_master         tinyint(1)            NO          NULL    
media             longblob              NO          NULL    
description       varchar(255)          YES         NULL    
time_stamp        datetime              YES         NULL
```

If I do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `accomodation_media`
WHERE id_accomodation = 7
AND is_master = true
```

return all the records where the **id_accomodatio** value is **7** and where the **is_master** value is **true**.

I want obtain something different:

I need the following behavior: if the **is_master** is setted to **true** have to be returned all the record that have the **is_master** setted bot true or false (the value of **is_master** is indifferent and not use it as filter).

If the **is_master** value is **false** have to return all the record that have **is_master* setted to **false**.

How can I change my query to do it?

Comment: Please show sample input and the output you want.  The question isn't entirely clear.  What is a `setted bot` ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the behaviour depending on a (global) parameter/variable you put into the querycode (maybe in a prepared statement, by using a parameter table, ...), so e.g. `$is_master` (not the per-row-value `is_master`)?: You can either use two different queries (e.g. `...where id_accomodation = 7` and `...where id_accomodation = 7 and is_master = false`), and choose the right code by the parameter, e.g. in php. Or, if you want to always use your parameter to keep the form/binding: `...where id_accomodation = 7 and (is_master = false or is_master = $is_master)`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column with type Int(1) this means an Integer with length 1.

So you can use 0 OR NULL for false and 1 as true

SELECT * FROM `accomodation_media`
WHERE id_accomodation = 7
AND is_master = 1

Comment: and what is the difference using a Boolean field as I do? I think nothing

Comment: @AndreaNobili Please show us input and output so that we don't have to guess.

Comment: You want a query which return ALL the data (every row) where the column ' is_master' settet to true?